# gcc flags equivalent to LD_PRELOAD?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld

I currently compile a program called `do_foo` like so:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g3 -pthread do_foo.c -o do_foo
```

and I run it like this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.. LD_PRELOAD=libfoo.so ./do_foo
```

`libfoo.so` is strange because:

1. Has a bunch of functions marked with `__attribute__((constructor))` and
2. Intercepts libc functions like `malloc`, `send`, etc

Instead of using `LD_PRELOAD` to link `libfoo.so`, I'd like to do it at compile time. I would expect to be able to do it like this:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g3 -L.. -lfoo -pthread do_foo.c -o do_foo_ld
```

but this doesn't work: none of the ctor functions run and none of the libc functions get intercepted. When I run `ldd do_foo_ld`, I don't see `libfoo.so` in the list of libraries linked to it.

What gcc flags are equivalent to `LD_PRELOAD`? I assume t here is some simple translation between the two, but I haven't been able to find it.

EDIT: I've made some progress with the following:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g3 -nodefaultlibs -pthread -L.. -lfoo -lc -lgcc do_foo.c -o do_foo_ld
```

My rationale is that I need to prevent loading libc at first with `-nodefaultlibs`, then link `libfoo.so`, then manually pull whatever gets taken out by `nodefaultlibs` in afterwards. With this, I don't get undefined reference errors about symbols from libc, but I do get the following:

```
/tmp/ccSsQHmx.o: In function `fun_1':
/my/proj/do_foo.c:217: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/tmp/ccSsQHmx.o: In function `fun_2':
/my/proj/do_foo.c:269: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/tmp/ccSsQHmx.o: In function `fun_3':
/my/proj/do_foo.c:281: undefined reference to `pthread_join'
```

No combination of `-pthread` `-lpthread` at various points in the `gcc` invocation seems to fix it, and I'm not sure why. I thought that `nodefaultlibs` might mean "prevent any of the default libraries from being linked" rather than just "don't link them yet," so I tried making a new symlink:

```
ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 ../libnotpthread.so
```

and adding the following:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g3 -nodefaultlibs -pthread -L.. -lfoo -lnotpthread -lc -lgcc do_foo.c -o do_foo_ld
```

but no dice.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe `libfoo.so` has a `SONAME`? You can check it with `objdump -p libfoo.so | grep SONAME`.

Comment: @rodrigo Nope, no result from that.

Answer (score 0):

You should put linked libraries *after* source or object files:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g3 do_foo.c -L.. -lfoo -pthread -o do_foo_ld
```

If this fails to work, try the big hammer:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g3 do_foo.c -Wl,--no-as-needed -L.. -lfoo -Wl,--as-needed -pthread -o do_foo_ld
```

Modern distroes enable `-Wl,--as-needed` flag by default which forces `-lfoo` to be ignored if none of preceding source or object files uses it (in your case there are no files so it's considered to be unused).